# If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and non-empty, but $A$ is not measurable, then $E\times A$ is not measurable in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I feel like this isn’t true. I came up with a counterexample but I’m not sure if this is valid since I am only a beginner.

Let $E$ be the singleton $\{0\}$. Then $E$ is measurable. Let $A$ be the Vitali set in $[0,1]$, then $A$ is not measurable. But $E\times A$ = Vitali set on $y$-axis in plane, which is null. Hence, as null sets are measurable, $E\times A$ is measurable. Hence the claim is false.

Is this argument valid?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: It depends on which $\sigma$-algebra you are considering on $\Bbb R^2$.  For Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $\Bbb R^2$, the your argument is correct.

Comment: @Ramiro Which algebra would it fail for?

Comment: Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in $\Bbb R^2$ is the **completion** of the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in each factor. This is key to make your argument to be correct. 

On the other hand, if you simply consider the product $\sigma$-algebra of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in each factor, this product $\sigma$-algebra is not complete. Your argument fails. In fact, we can prove that $A \times B$ is measurable in the product $\sigma$-algebra if and only if $A$ and $B$ are measurable.